# jQuery's hover event type is printed as mouseover and mouseenter

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, console

See this photo:

[image]

Is this a bug or the standard?

PS: mouseover after args is just a label.

## Event listener

```
$ ->
  $('.bigger-on-hover').hover (event) ->

    console.log 'args'
    console.log arguments
    console.log @
    window.x = arguments
    window.y = @
    console.log 'args'
    console.log 'mouseover'
    console.log event.type
```

Comment: Can you show the code from the event listener? Did you use jQuery?

Comment: yes. yes. updating...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mouseenter is in Internet Explorer only, but jQuery mimics it in other browsers.

your `event` is actually the jQuery event, so its type is `mouseenter`.

To see the native event, use `event.originalEvent`. You can see its type with `console.log(event.originalEvent.type)`. In non-IE, that type is `mouseover`.

jQuery listened for that mouseover event, and when it heard it, it checked to see if the mouse pointer was already over that element, found that it wasn't, and then fired a jQuery mouseenter event. It then changed the event back to `mouseover` so that it would have normal effects as it bubbled.

When you use `.hover()`, jQuery listens for these enter and leave events to trigger it on and off.

Answer (score 1):

[`jQuery.fn.hover`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/85fc5878b3c6af73f42d61eedf73013e7faae408/src/event-alias.js#L14-L16) is an alias:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    hover: function( fnOver, fnOut ) {
        return this.mouseenter( fnOver ).mouseleave( fnOut || fnOver );
```

Those `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` methods themselves are also [just shortcuts](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/85fc5878b3c6af73f42d61eedf73013e7faae408/src/event-alias.js#L1-L11) with [special treatment](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/85fc5878b3c6af73f42d61eedf73013e7faae408/src/event.js#L670-L692).

The object printed by `console.log` is not a frozen snapshot. If the object is modified before the object is expanded, the modified version will be logged to the console. And that's what happened here.